Failed to connect to the existing server farm located at the specified database server and database name. The db name is not a valid configuration
I have a two server SharePoint 2016 farm. PROD1 which contain SharePoint and SQL1 which contain database. Now I am trying to join another SharePoint server called PROD2 to the farm.
Both PROD1 and PROD2 are Windows 2019.
Installation is done but when I am trying to run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, it is showing following error:

Failed to connect to the existing server farm located at the specified
database server and database name. The database name is not a valid
configuration database.


Port 1433 is open as I can telnet database server. Plus, this alias is created in both 32 and 64 bit using cliconfg.exe
Whether I log in as SPSetup (which was the account that was used to do first SharePoint PROD1 installation or SPFarm which is farm account, both have same error. Both accounts have dbcreator and sysadmin permission in database and local admin on this PC.
Is it happening because there is a certain Windows KB update that needs to be installed? This is a fresh machine with no Windows updates so may be this is the issue?
Or do I need to first install SharePoint CU on this new server similar to the one being used on PROD1?
PROD1 is at 16.0.5426.1000 which is December 2023 CU. While PROD2 (the new server) is at 16.0.4351.1000 which is RTM.
How to fix this issue?
EDIT
In event viewer, I am getting following error:
SharePoint object is in an unsupported state, and could not be used by the current farm
Does this mean I have to run Products Configuration Wizard on existing production server first as it says "Upgrade Required"
OR
I have make the new server equal to current one by applying December 2023 CU (as current server is at this level)?

Yes, you have to ensure the current farm build number be as same as or higher than the first farm build number.
In this case, you have to do one of two solutions before running SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard.
1.Install the latest cumulative update on both farms to ensure that the farm build number is the same.
2.Patch the lower farm build number with the same update in the destination build number.

The new server should have same CU as the current one. Once you do that, running product configuration wizard won't show error.
